# Your system doesnt allow me to ask a question

Tags: support

My question is: Why do they transport naked in time in Terminator universe? Does it ever explained in movies or tv serials?

Error is: It does not meet our quality standards.

Comment: Like Keen said, just try to flesh out the question more. We survive by having high quality questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After playing around a bit, it seems like you get that error if you ask too short a question.  I'd suggest fleshing out the body of the question with more background detail.  Discuss how each of the time travelers in the Terminator movies and TV shows pop into existence in the past naked.